# Dragging out of canvas causes selection of page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

Currently I'm creating an web application with KineticJS, which includes dragging and dropping on a canvas. It works perfectly fine, when you keep your mouse inside your canvas.

However, if you leave the canvas, with your left mouse button pressed, you will select everything on the page. Is possible to intercept that event in some way. Obviously onselect is something else :p

Comment: I guess I'd look into preventing the event from propagating. If you leave the canvas after getting a mousedown, but before getting a mouse-up, your user is dragging. I think I'd intercept mouseover, mouseout on the canvas, mousemove on the document. If the flags I set indicated that I didn't want the event getting passed on, I'd try to kill it with preventDefault. Not sure it would work. In the middle of trying to implement something like the reverse, since IE doesn't know about the "pointer-events: none" CSS rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encapsulated the canvas element into a div and then assigned the event handlers onto the div, the div covers 100% of the page's layout like:

```
<div class="fillPage">
    <canvas id="Viewport"></canvas>
</div>
```

I also added event handlers for blur (page-leave) and the following css:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for your comment! In my situation however, it's not possible to do that. There's content on de website, and the canvas is in the middle of this content. So I do want the content to be selectable, just not when you're leaving the canvas with your mouse down.

Perhaps I can work with the user-select a bit, combined with an onmouseout of the select! Didn't know about that CSS.

Comment: hm, you could also try to stop the mousedown event fired as the mouse leaves the canvas, there might be some js functions for it